# What is the best way to store data in a Leaderboard table where every column must support ordering?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, leaderboard

I'm currently re-building a Leaderboard for a game using an external API, where every stat in the game can be viewed as a separate leaderboard. There are over 150+ stats for which only few players have all of them, and most would probably have around 50-100 of them. These stats are stuff like different weapons used, time played, number of kills etc.

The currently live version uses an approach I don't like, but I cant think of a better solution. As `ORDER BY` needs to be available for every stat, I have a massive table with 150+ columns, each column is one of the stats, and this table now has about 200 thousand rows. The columns that are indexed work ok, but I ran out of indexes as MySQL only allows 64 in total, and the columns that arent indexed load incredibly slowly, even when I'm looking at the first 50 rows of the data.

I thought about splitting up the stats by category, and having 6 or so tables with less columns in them, but this meant that I had to join tables together if someone wanted to look at Weapon x (Weapons category) and Games played (Main stats category) at the same time.

As well as supporting a Leaderboard for each of the stats, there also needs to be support for leaderboards created by ratios, the most common being kills / deaths, kills / games, wins / games. In my live version this is supported, but its really slow and when I'm trying to view the leaderboard for Weapon x kills per game ( weapon x / games played ) it takes a few seconds to load the first 50 results and this is when both columns are within the same table.

When player stats are added, the old row containing their stats is marked as historical data, so that the leaderboard queries can just consider live data and this did improve my performance as I didn't have to use `MAX(column)` to find the correct value for the player. But I do want to keep this historical data in the table somehow so that people can view historical leaderboards.

Aside from a table with a column for every stat, I thought about a table with one column called `stat_id`and one column called `count`, but when I tried to implement it I realised that if on average each player has 50 stats and there are over 200 thousand rows already, then the new table will have over a million rows that will require a JOIN on every query to find out what the stat_id is.

I might have already answered my own question that a table with a column for every stat really is the best option, but I also think there must be something I've failed to realise or another method that might improve performance especially when dealing with the issue of calculating leaderboard positions for players that currently takes 50 seconds - 2 minutes for every column.

This is the current Leaderboard query for the "Live leaderboard" (excluding historical data), where `$columnsToSelect` is a string list of column names and sometimes ratio of columns, and `$this->params` is a parameters object that users can use to customize the results set. Players with less than 50 games are not stored in the leaderboard table, and the query is ordered by Id as well so that the exact position of a player can be found, and with that the page they are on can be found.

```
$sql = "SELECT s.`id`, `player`, $columnsToSelect, `lastupdated`;
        FROM stats_table as s
        WHERE $orderColumn <> 0
        AND `historical` = 0
        AND `banned` = 0 " . (
            $this->params["mingames"] > 50 ? (
                "AND `gamesplayed` >= " . $this->params["mingames"] 
            ) : ""
        );

$sql .= " AND ($orderColumn, s.id) <= (?, ?)
              ORDER BY $orderColumn DESC, s.`id` DESC
              LIMIT " . $this->params["rows"];
```

Comment: Can you show your current query (I assume LIMIT is used to get the top X leaders)

Comment: I don't understand `AND ($orderColumn, s.id) <= (?, ?)`. And what is a `banned` column doing in a stats table - unless players want to compare how often they've been banned

Comment: @Strawberry the AND clause is a seek predicate to avoid having to use LIMIT and OFFSET. The banned column should be in the players table, but I thought that doing that  join would hurt the performance

Answer (score 0):

MySQL isn't the best database solution for sorting on every column.

Did you ever look into MariaDB Columnar store?

https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/01/30/mariadb-columnstore/

If you can't do that, another solution is to limit the results enough to push the sorting (outside MySQL) to the client app.